# WooCommerce checkout layout

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the layout of my WooCommerce checkout page, but I can't figure out how to do it since it seems to consist of multiple PHP pages.

What I'm trying to achieve is moving the summary part and shipping info to the top, and have the input fields for the shipping address shown afterwards.

Should I make these changes using CSS, or can I simply change the order of the hooks in the template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the "woocommerce/templates/checkout" folder there is a file called "form-checkout.php". Copy the contents of that file to "yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php" On line ~54 there is the following code:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
```

Move that to just below

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>">
```

and add:

```
<?php
$order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" />' );
?>
```

to just below the

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

and save file the. That will bring the summary and shipping to above the input fields, but you will still have "Place Order" button at the top of the page. Copy the contents of the "review-order.php" to "yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php" and remove the following (from line ~169):

```
<?php
$order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" />' );
?>
```

Removing the above will remove the "Place order" button at the top of the page.

You can edit the "form-check.php" file in "woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php", but it is not recommended as when you update woocommerce you will lose those changes. Copying the file to "yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php" will [override](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) the file and you won't lose those changes if you update woocommerce.

Comment: Thank you. That almost works. Only problem is that it's also moving the submit button to the top, so the layout is now like this; 
summary and shipping, submit order, then address.

Can I keep the submit order in the bottom, but have the rest of the summary in the top?

Comment: @user2806026 sorry about that, check my answer I have edited in how to move the submit button to below the input fields.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much! A bit more work was needed though; in order to get the 'Your order' text moved to the top as well, I also moved the line 
`<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>`

To form-checkout. Now, the only thing left to do is to remove the gray divider bar which is normally below the submit button, but has been moved to the top along with the summary. I can remove it from the top by deleting the div form-row place-order line, I just cant figure out how to get it inserted in the button again. Your help is really appreciated. THanks!

Comment: The mentioned line is place around line 161 in review-order.php. By deleting it, it dissappears from the top but nothing happens when I insert it in form-checkout.php instead

Comment: @user2806026 add a div around the submit button and add the styles there e.g. `background: #f7f6f7; padding: 20px;` The styles would be added to the styles.css file.

Comment: Great. I have moved the divider bar by hiding it in the top and displaying it under the checkout button instead. After inserting terms and conditions and payment method, this shows up in the top below the summary as well. Can you tell me how to move this? :-)