# Reorder woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, layout, woocommerce, checkout

I'm looking to reorder the WooCommerce Checkout page. It's almost like the post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077335/woocommerce-checkout-layout).

But I would like the payment section to remain at the bottom but I can seem to be able to separate the order info and the payment info.

The layout I would like to achieve is

```
    - CART REVIEW INFO
    - BILLING/SHIPPING INFO
    - PAYMENT INFO
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to edit the form-checkout.php file within:
public_html/yourfolder/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout

Within this file you'll see the html skeleton, with the php injectors/hooks within.

You'll need to look for the div's that contain the billing/shipping info and the cart review/payment info.

Once you've found these, you'll need to move the hooks for the *billing/shipping info* into a newly created div/container **between** the *cart review/payment info* information.

billing/shipping info hooks:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>
```

Be careful, in some cases moving the payment info out of the order_review div can cause the checkout to stop working.