# Woocommerce checkout layout customisation "Place Order" button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have combined cart and checkout on one page and are moving things around in the layout but cannot properly move Place order button on the checkout from file payment.php to cart.php. The button shows is clickable but not able to pas the checkout as it gives an error: "We were unable to process your order, please try again."

Followed this guide below on removing and adding the button:

[WooCommerce checkout layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077335/woocommerce-checkout-layout)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to understand. `payment.php` template is a part of `form-checkout.php` and it is residing inside  tag. Also on the `cart.php` page , you can found that there is also all the data resides inside the `<form>` tag.

You need to place your place order button including with other page information that needed for the checkout inside the `form` tag with proper form name and action to make it worth on the cart page.

Comment: I have tried this but still have not worked, do you know why this jquery code does not work I hide the button and create a new one which triggers that one : jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.zk').on('click',function(){
        
        jQuery('.button.alt').trigger('click');
    });
});